# Sending a TAB control character in Java

Tags: java, ssh, inputstream

I am using the Ganymede ssh library (http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/)
to connect to a ssh server (obviously ;)).

Normally, when using the bash, when a user presses the TAB key on the keyboard a list of possible command completions appears. I want to achieve the same behaviour, but send the tab character manually. Unfortunately I am not aware how to do this. Sending "\t" does not work.

**Edit:** The solution must be a generic which does not only work in bash, but also in other programs, like octave (open source matlab implementation with command line, just an example where bash commands cannot be applied).

Comment: Chances are that any shells you start via this connection don't enable their interactive features unless there's a terminal attached at your end. So either find a switch on those shells to force them to enable that behaviour anyway or "lie" to them by requesting a terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Joachim Sauer said, this is probably because your session does not have a terminal attached, so programs such as Bash will behave as though they have been called non-interactively.

The documentation for Ganymede ssh library implies that calling session.requestPTY(...) will ask the SSH server to attach a pseudo TTY to the session. It is like passing the "-t" flag to the ssh command.

Code sample:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection;
import ch.ethz.ssh2.Session;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Main().test();
    }

    private Session sess;

    public void test() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Connection c  = new Connection("myserver", 22);
        c.connect();
        boolean OK = c.authenticateWithPassword("user", "pass");
        if (!OK) throw new IOException("Bad password");
        sess = c.openSession();
        sess.requestPTY("vt220");
        new Thread(stdoutLogger).start();
        sess.execCommand("/bin/bash");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        sess.getStdin().write("echo Hello\n".getBytes());
        sess.getStdin().write("ls -l /tm\t".getBytes());
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        sess.close();
        c.close();
    }

    Runnable stdoutLogger = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            InputStream is = sess.getStdout();
            int b;
            try {
                while ( (b = is.read()) != -1) {
                    System.out.println("Read " + b + " - " + (char)b);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried the requestPTY method. But how to proceed then? What should I send to issue a TAB key press?

Comment: I think just sending a tab character as you suggested should work. The following works for me:

sess = c.openSession(); sess.requestPTY("vt220"); sess.execCommand("/bin/bash"); sess.getStdin().write("ls -l /tm\t".getBytes());

Comment: Thanks. That works out very well. you could also send the byte '9' twice which is the representation for the TAB control chracter. I don't know why I did not find the solution myself, really simple ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command :

```
compgen -c
```

It list all possible commands in the shell. You may add

```
grep <something>
```

to filter the output

Comment: @Erik: seen that you specifically wrote that you want to simulate a *tab* to, your words, *"...list of possible command completions..."* and seen that *compgen* list all possible commands, StKiller thought this would help you.  You probably didn't phrase your question/example well enough.

Comment: Okay I see. Thanks a lot for the point. I try to clarify my question, see my post.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't what you're talking about dependent on the command shell? I don't think '\t' works because that's the tab character, not the tab keypress which gets interpreted by your shell as a command that lists the possible command completions.

As this is a library you're asking about, it seems to me what you want, you'd have to implement yourself as the shell normally handles that, I think.